# Golang парсинг xml CDATA

Tags: xml, golang

Имею xml:

```
`<name>11
    <![CDATA[Arman]]>
  </name>`
```

Дело в том что в поле `name` иногда попадают левые символы которые мне не нужны
Т.е. распарсивая xml получаю:

```
11
    Arman
```

А нужно получить только имя пользователя: Arman

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/QNR9viUbcFv

Comment: Т.е. необходимо получить значения только внутри CDATA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечу сам. На данный момент в стандартных библиотеках нет возможности парсинга только раздела CDATA. Поэтому все делается ручками))